# Error in generating a latex file from a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was given a task to accomplish some questions from a jupyter notebook (.ipynb) which I did.
Now the problem arises upon submission I get an error.

I have installed the packages using the following commands;
pip install nbconvert
sudo apt-get install pandoc
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic

```
but after running grader.export() I get the following error;

There was an error generating your LaTeX; showing full error message:
================================================================================
Failed to run "['xelatex', 'notebook.tex', '-quiet']" command:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eurosym/eurosym.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/grffile/grffile.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-xetex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/atveryend/atveryend.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `[FandolSong-Regular.otf]/OT', contains '['


Package xeCJK Warning: Fandol is being set as the default font for CJK text.
(xeCJK)                Please make sure it has been properly installed.


! Package fontspec Error: The font "FandolSong-Regular" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.307 \begin{document}
                      
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.307 \begin{document}
                      
No pages of output.
Transcript written on notebook.log.

================================================================================
If the error above is related to xeCJK or fandol in LaTeX and you don't require this functionality, try running again with no_xecjk set to True or the --no-xecjk flag.
/home/jupyter-deus.francis/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/otter/check/notebook.py:328: UserWarning: Could not locate a PDF to include
  warnings.warn("Could not locate a PDF to include")
```

Comment: This is fundamentally a LaTeX question and might be better suited to the LaTeX stackexchange.

Comment: Also, what code did you run to make the LaTeX document? What is the source of the LaTeX document?